# Are there any other foods that are improved by grilling?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I was wandering further into my dungeon, when suddenly a wild charcoal grill appeared!  I used steak on it, which was super effective.  However, I'm wondering what else I can grill besides steak.

Are there any other food or item types that are improved by dropping them on a lit charcoal grill?

Comment: Voting to close, should be migrated to cooking.se

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, I've got a lit charcoal grill, a pile of lutefisk, and I can breathe fire.  We'll see *who migrates who!*

Comment: I'd be more scared if you could breathe lutefisk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Containers#Dungeon_Features):

> BBQ [grill] - Never locked, may contain food. If you put any steak on it, you will get a grilled steak.

From that, and my failed attempts to cook my various cheeses, I don't think you can cook anything other than steak.

Comment: Confirmed IRL - the cheese simply falls through the grill grate.

Tried a frying pan instead, was rewarded with a stink and a crispy hunk of stuff that tastes much like a Cheez-It.